# Stuck on datetime to date conversion

Tags: sql

perhaps someone can help me, I am pulling my hair out over this conversion I'm trying to do.  I have a query that returns a few columns.  One of them is a column of values in a long hand DateTime format.  I want to add a column next to this one and trim the date to remove the time so that it is just MM-DD-YYYY

my SQL so far is just a union.  I don't know where such code would go or what it would be.  Cannot figure out how to get it to work with CAST or Convert

```
select * from (
  SELECT top 3 Ref_Date, COUNT(Ref_Date) AS Count, 'Trim' as Ref_DateTrimmed
  FROM [STORAGE_DW].[dbo].[SRM_VirtualMachines]
      group by Ref_Date
  order by Ref_Date desc
  ) a 
UNION
select * from (
 SELECT top 3 Ref_Date, COUNT(Ref_Date) AS Count, 'Trim' as Ref_DateTrimmed
  FROM [STORAGE_DW].[dbo].[SRM_PhysicalHosts]
     group by Ref_Date
  order by Ref_Date desc 
  ) b
```

returned column is this:

```
Ref_Date
2017-01-16 02:27:00.000
2017-01-16 07:05:00.000
2017-01-23 02:24:00.000
2017-01-23 07:01:00.000
2017-01-30 02:36:00.000
2017-01-30 07:03:00.000
```

Comment: Update your question and: 1) Tag your DBMS (sql-server, oracle, etc) as well as the version. 2) Provide the data type for the column `ref_date`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 You can use this: CONVERT(DATE, Ref_Date, 101) as 'Trim'
```

Comment: that worked in that it got the very last part to 00.000 but i need to cut off t he time so that it's just a date so I can effectively use group.  this is an example of a record after your code (thank you by the way)

Comment: 2017-01-16 02:27:00.000

Comment: what i need it to say is 2017-01-16